# Radio button selection and stylize ul via jquery help!

Tags: jquery, input, radio-button, html-lists

I have the following jsfiddle setup:

http://jsfiddle.net/5bFq7/8/

basically I have a ul list and when a user selects a li the previous selected li should have the id active removed and the new selected one should have the id active applied to it. Also there are radio buttons, in the li when a new li is selected the corresponding radio button should be selected.

Please can someone help with this as my jquery is awful!

Thanks

Comment: You probably want to go back and accept answers to some of your past questions too. You seem to have a fair few unanswered which never looks good when people are working out whether its worth the time to help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML isn't that hot either. ;-) Your radio buttons weren't really radio buttons.

http://jsfiddle.net/chrisvenus/5bFq7/16/

is a working copy of the code in terms of selecting a radio button and highlighting the correct options. Changes include to how selectors were being done, where the click event was (on the li instead of the ul), etc.

Comment: Thanks, so much!!!! I did cut and paste quite a bit hence messy code. But solution works beautifully!

Comment: Hopefully you can see that what you were trying to do was overcomplicating things a lot. In general use classes and not IDs to set stuff and if you find yourself concatenating strings to create stuff then often (but not always) you're making things too complicated. :)

Comment: Thanks, I definitely need to work with js and jquery again, its been way too long!